# Repeat CURL code on getting errors and logged in php

Tags: php, curl, while-loop

I want to keep this code in loop(twice/thrice) when curl_error is true and if still fail, make entry in error log.

```
$ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

/* if there is an error show error */
if (curl_error($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
    $success = false;
    return view('frontend.user.rss', compact('project_detail_all','active_project_detail','rss_detail','success'));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Kindly give your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: do you want to run this curl 2-3 times ? you can use php for loop https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: i know looping in php , but my concern is " loop when error occurs and if still fails loged into error file "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do much `curl`ing but this seems like a logical way...

```
$i=0;
do{
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    /* if there is an error show error */
    if(curl_error($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)!=200){
        $success=false;
    }else{
        $success=true;
        break;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    ++$i;
}while($i<3);

if($success){
    // return what you want / $response
}else{
    // log the failure, return what you want
    // return view('frontend.user.rss', compact('project_detail_all','active_project_detail','rss_detail','success'));
}
```

Comment: @wasimbeg  What this does is breaks the loop as soon as it has `$success=true`; if first iteration is `$success=false` it loops a maximum of two more times.  If `$success` remains false after 3 attempts, it exits the loop and you can log the error - one time.  If this is not what you want, please clarify with a comment on question edit.